Connect DataForm to PostgreSql
I am trying to create a query that combine tables from BigQuery and Postgresql. I can access BQ easly since  it's related to DataForm, but I'm lost for PG. A coworker told me that it's possible to access PG from DF but I can't find any information related to that on Google. I connected DataForm to a service account that's has all the right on both databases.
Does someone know if it's feasible please?
I tried to put the json code to connect to PG in 'dataform.json' but it seem obsolete since a recent version. Tried it on 'workflow_settings.yaml' but it don't seem to accept it either.
